# Search doesn't find all posts

Tags: support, search

I was looking for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709356/warn-user-of-unsaved-data-in-jsf/5709834#5709834), so I searched using [user:me onbeforeunload](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:157882%20onbeforeunload) (actually, I *initially* used [user:me [jsf] onbeforeunload](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:157882%20%5Bjsf%5D%20onbeforeunload) which didn't find anything). However it returns only one result. I am pretty certain that I've used that word in *at least* 10 posts.

I also get a single result when I search on [user:me setdateheader](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:157882%20setdateheader). This should be *at least* 40 posts. The same for [user:me setheader](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:157882%20setheader). This should be many more.

Where are those posts? Or were they considered duplicates in some way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it were, search appears to treat `x.y` as a single word, so "onbeforeunload" doesn't match [window.onbeforeunload](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A157882+window.onbeforeunload). Or any similar construct, like [response.setheader](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A157882+response.setheader).

Unfortunately, there's no wildcard functionality (that I can find) for searching with normal terms rather than tags. This seems like something that should be addressed, as it inhibits the ability to search for methods and the like which are *only* contained in the code block.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you! I however wonder if this is by design or not. If I recall correctly, the previous version of Search (over half a year ago or something) didn't consider `x.y` as a single word.

Comment: @Chichiray I don't know. I don't remember if this was how it always worked or not, but I don't often have to search for method stuff.

Comment: After a thought, it makes somewhat sense to treat `x.y` as a single word. This way it's easier indexing/searching for abbreviations, specific methods, internet addresses and on. I'll just keep this "feature" in mind from now on. Thank you for answering :)