# How do I search for class members?

Tags: support, search

I was trying to search for a class member, and it was really a huge (negative) surprise that SE search engine does not work as expected:

[[f#] foldBack](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[f%23]+foldBack) (12 results)
[[f#] List.foldBack](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[f%23]+List.foldBack) (21 results, mostly **different** ones)

Seriously, I consider it's a mission critical for **programmer's site** a to be able to search for frequently used programming items like member methods, variables, events, classes, and namespaces.

So I checked here on Meta and found that indeed, [Search doesn't find all posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92784/search-doesnt-find-all-posts)

Since [Search Options](https://stackoverflow.com/search) doesn't have anything relevant, I guess, nothing has changed since then.

Hence, the question: Are there any hints for uniform searching for `class.member` or `namespace.member`? Except GIYF, of course.

Comment: Actually, Google is the first place I go for searches like these.  You can confine your search to Stack Overflow by adding  `site:stackoverflow.com` to your search request.

Comment: @RobertHarvey This *is* GIYF answer! :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `code:` operator, if you are looking for something included in code blocks, such as with [[f#] code:"foldBack"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bf%23%5D%20code:%22foldBack%22&submit=search), or [[f#] code:"List.foldBack"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bf%23%5D+code%3A%22List.foldBack%22&submit=search).

Comment: The first link returns only 5 results. I've checked them; all five contain "bare" word `foldBack`, so it does not seem to be any more helpful. However I do think `code` prefix should be added on [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/search). Google [returns](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22f%23%22+%22foldBack%22") 344 results, which sounds believable.

Comment: [Why is the "code:" search option not documented?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146827/why-is-the-code-search-option-not-documented)